# Remove from inside div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a script that is supposed to render text (later a partial view) inside a div on click. I detect if div is visible or not and if not, I add text on click and make the div visible. This part works perfectly. When clicked and the div is visible I want to remove what has been added so that it wont multiply if I click it multiple times.

I get both alert - so detection of div visibility works but the text is not removed and it multiplies if I click it many times.

Here is my code - can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".content").hide();
        $(".heading").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var content = $(this).next(".content");

            if (content.is(":hidden")) {
                content.append("<p id='render-object'>Testing rendering on click</p>");
                alert('Content is opening');
            }
            else if (content.is(":visible")) {
                content.next("#render-object").remove();
                alert('Content is closing');
            }

            content.slideToggle(100);                
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">` for starters

Comment: ok - but it works anyway :)

Comment: don't think you need type for html5

Comment: you don't need to do `else if (content.is(":visible")) {` simply `else {` will work. If content is not hidden it can only be visible right (boolean). And yes - do `content.empty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".content").hide();
        $(".heading").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var content = $(this).next(".content");

            if (content.is(":hidden")) {
                content.html("<p id='render-object'>Testing rendering on click</p>");
                alert('Content is opening');
            }
            else if (content.is(":visible")) {
                content.find("#render-object").remove();
                alert('Content is closing');
            }

            content.slideToggle(100);                
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit** : - use `.find()` instead of `.next()` as `render-object` is child of `content` and not sibling

Comment: Yeah :) Now it's working. Can you tell me what's the diffrent between .html() and .append() ?  PS: i will accept answer in 10 minutes

Comment: `.html()` replaces all contents inside div but `.append()` keep on adding to the original contents

Comment: This is not really the correct, you are not properly removing the content otherwise append would work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of .next() when removing.

Comment: Ok cool, just note that you you could keep using .append() if you changed .next() to .find().

Answer (score 0):

use `.find` instead of `.next` and use `.html` instead of `.append`

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".heading").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var content = $(".content");

        if (content.is(":hidden")) {
            content.html("<p id='render-object'>Testing rendering on click</p>");
            alert('Content is opening');
        }
        else if (content.is(":visible")) {
            content.find("#render-object").remove();
            alert('Content is closing');
        }

        content.slideToggle(100);                
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: three changes! var content = $(this).find(".content") as well.

Comment: find with #renderobject works but i when i do find to .content it's not working so i gues it got to do something with parenting

Comment: is .heading a parent of .content? if they are siblings use .next. If .content is nested somewhere else use $('.content')